# "Universal" Flash grabber

Tags: flash

If there is no native flash player on a machine (e.g. OBSD amd64) then could someone mention good methods for getting the various flash content (only videos!) from the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.downloadhelper.net/ is an addon for Firefox, which is capable of downloading Flash video from a whole lot of web sites. As far as I know, it doesn't use native code components, so it should work on OpenBSD, too.

It's possible that it requires flash on some sites to figure out the video URLs (it seems to intercept the plugin's http requests, which are routed through the browser), but I'm quite sure that it can directly derive the right URLs on the popular video sites (eg. youtube).

It also can't download rtmp streams, as these are handled by the plugin, not delegated to the browser. For those streams, [rtmpdump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) should come in handy.